# Calculate number of permutations in a set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I came across an interesting problem that I can't solve. I start with a list of all numbers 0-99 inclusive, and then add 50 (*n*) random numbers from 0-99 to that list. The result is then shuffled using an algorithm. My initial thought was that the number of permutations would be 150!/2<sup>50</sup>, but quickly realized that this is only the case if each number added at the end is unique. Obviously that is not the case, since the numbers are random.

My question is: how would the number of permutations be calculated (for *n*=50 or any *n*)? It would have to account for the possibility that any given number could be generated 50 times (plus the original), which would vastly expand the set.

Comment: Are the random numbers you are adding distinct?

Comment: No. They are all independently generated.

Comment: It is easy(?) to compute the total number of arrangements (with possible repetitions) as $100^{150}$, among which a certain fraction do not include every possible number $0$ to $99$.  So I would use the approach of Markov processes to work out what fraction include every possible number versus what fraction do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a formula you need to include some parameter describing the result of the random generation (how many repeats were generated).  This could be done by a list $(a_1,...,a_i)$ where $1 \leq a_k \leq n$ and $\sum a_i = n$.  Then you can use this to count permutations.  You have $100+n$ numbers to permute so there are $(100+n)!$ ways to do this, but you need to identify permutations which give the same result, so you need to divide by $(a_1+1)!(a_2+1)! \cdots (a_i+1)!$ giving $$\frac{(100+n)!}{(a_1+1)!(a_2+1)! \cdots (a_i+1)!}$$

In the case where you generate $n=50$ distinct numbers like you assumed to start, your list would be $(1,1,...,1)$ with $50$ entries, which gives the result you stated in your question.

Comment: If you were looking for an average/expected number of permutations on generating $n$ random numbers you could read about the probability mass function for [multinomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

Comment: Great answer, but that's pretty much what I'd already figured out (no offense). I'll definitely look into the multinomial distributions.

I just had no idea if there was a "simple" answer that I was completely missing. With the need for a parameter, that basically describes what I was thinking in that there is no way to determine the total number of permutations without knowing the number of repeats.